# How can go to the previous fragment in backstack?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a MainActivity in the `onCreate` method i add a fragment like this :

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentA(), FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack("main")
                .commit();
```

In `FragmentA` there is a lisview and when user clicked on an item i remove `FragmentA` and add `FragmentB` (In `FragmentA` there is a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and in `FragmentPagerAdapter` is a `ListFragment` in `ListFragment` i called below code )

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB(), MainActivity.FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack("main")
                        .commit();
};
```

Now in `FragmentB` there is button and whenever user clicked on it i want to go back to the `FragmentA`.
I try to call `popBackStack()`in button listener but nothing happen

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Or i also try this below code but it gives me nullpointer exception

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        String fragmentTag = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        Fragment currentFragment =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,currentFragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Comment: On what line did the nullpointer exception occur?, also calling 'replace' in the transaction does not add it to the backstack, the method 'add' however does. I did see you added it programmaticaly, but calling add should suffice

Comment: I got exception in  >fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
i also try add instead of replace but same exception happen

Comment: Try adding fragmentManager.popBackStack("main")

Comment: But it goes me to the MainActivity without any fragmens in content_frame

Comment: Ok, maybe try using different Tags so that when you use findFragmentByTag it wont get mixed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go to the previous `Fragment` in the `BackStack`, then all you need to do is call `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Thanks it works. But i have a problem with this , if i go to the first method (before the fragmentA initializing for the first time) it show me the activity layout ,i want whenever user came to this onDestroy method called (for example if user is in fragmentB and click on back button he goes to fragmentA and when he click on back button again he goes to MainActivity , i don't want user come to the MainActivity anymore )

Comment: getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() is always zero .

Comment: try using `.addToBackStack(null)`

Comment: I use getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() and my problem solved,Thanks